# Why is the Redirection not working in webview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, webview, navigation

I am doing mindbody authentication using OAuth2 2.0.1 package in flutter,I am getting the response url,but after authentication its not redirecting back to the app with the response url.
Attached my code

```
  Future<NavigationDecision> navigationDelegateCallback(
     BuildContext context, NavigationRequest navigationRequest) async {
   if (navigationRequest.url.startsWith(redirectUri.toString())) {
   try {
    Navigator.pop(
      context,
      IDPAuthResult.fromRedirectUri(
        Uri.tryParse(navigationRequest.url)!,
      ),
    );
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    }
   }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
   }
```

how to navigate to the app with result?